# Combining more than 2 expressions in Expression Trees

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to use Expression trees to create dynamic linq queries.

I was wondering how I can combine 3 expressions using AND/OR.

Lets say I have 3 expressions a, b , c and if I use

```
Expression z = Expression.Or(a,b); 
Expression result = Expression.And(z,c);
```

The result  I get is (a Or b) And c. However, I want (a Or b And c). Is that even possible?

**EDIT**
I will try again. 
I have got Expressions to create my dynamic queries. My source data is XML which looks like the following

```
  <Filter>      
    <Expression>
      <operator>
        Equal
      </operator>
      <Left>
        <property>RecStatus</property>            
      </Left>

      <Right>
        <constant type="char">D</constant>            
      </Right>
    </Expression>
</Filter>
```

Each filter can have many expressions and I parse this xml and create dynamic expressions. However, when I combine more then 2 expressions, they appear in brackets eg. (A AND B) and when I try to append the third one, the result becomes ((A AND B) AND C) and this continues. I want to be able to control how the brackets are being applied as this changes the operator precedence (unless the user creating the XML was vary of the final effects). I was wondering if there is a way to control this behavior or if there is an alternate (better) way of doing this.

Comment: `(a Or b And c)` is the same as `(a Or (b And c))`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Either I havent understood your comment or you havent understood my question. Please have a look at the edited version.

Comment: The parentheses around the equality expression are redundant, plus you changed the original question to reverse, now you want (a OR b) AND c, originally you complained about to get (a OR b) AND c and wanted a OR b AND c which is a OR (b AND c)

Comment: You are right. I need to articulate the question properly. Hang in there while I do that.

Comment: @Farax: After your current edit your question is contradictory

Comment: *“I want to be able to control how the brackets are being applied”* – You already control them precisely by calling `Expression.Or` and `Expression.And` with *two* arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31740043/147511), an [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression) tree is set of connected instances of `Expression.BinaryExpression` and/or the unary-branching `Expression` types--these are called the "*non-terminals*", plus additional self-valued `Expression.Expression` instances (*terminals*, or "leaf" nodes), and which is referred to by a distinguished root. Most expression trees can be informally characterized as either ***left-branching*** or ***right-branching***, in reference to its general overall branching direction below the root.

Because evaluation of an expression tree's root node depends on the value(s) of its children, the root node is evaluated **last**. This means that **C#** statements and other linear/written sequences of concatenated operators which are subject to ***left-to-right operator precedence*** will generally manifest as **left-branching** expression trees.

For example, since the expression `48 - 1 - 2 - 3` needs to be evaluated as `(((48 - 1) - 2) - 3)`, it must have this left-branching structure in order to get the correct answer of `42`:

[image]

For the same expression `48 - 1 - 2 - 3`, the **right-branching** tree implies `(48 - (1 - (2 - 3)))`, which gives a different, incorrect answer, `-48`:

[image]

As it turns out, this means that given a typical expression subject to left-to-right precedence--whether written, machine-readable `String`, or some other representation of a linear, ordered sequence of operators--you can build a tree with the correct operator precedence by scanning from left-to-right in the order given while then, for each iteration, pushing the previous node down to the `BinaryExpression.Left` side.

Since faulty operator precedence will only produce incorrect results for [commutative operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), we'll use subtraction as an example. As noted, for the normal forward-scanning case, a simple loop builds the correct left-branching expression tree.

```
static Expression L_to_R_Forward(IEnumerable<Expression> seq)
{
    Expression root = null;
    foreach (var cur in seq)
        root = root == null ? cur : Expression.Subtract(root, cur);

    return root;
}
```

To demonstrate the use of this method, we start with a natural representation of the desired left-to-right expression `48 - 1 - 2 - 3`, which is the  ordered sequence `{ 48, 1, 2, 3 }`. We convert this to a sequence of integer `ConstantExpression` instances, and pass it to the method shown above at runtime to get the desired `Expression` root. This, in turn, is then compiled into a delegate `func` that you can call (repeatedly, if you like) to obtain the result.

```
var seq = new[] { 48, 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => Expression.Constant(i));

var root = L_to_R_Forward(seq);  // root <- '((48 - 1) - 2) - 3'

var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(root).Compile();

int result = func();          // result <-- 42 (ok!)
```

This all works great, so for this most common case, a simple loop is sufficient and you don't have to use recursion--a technique often associated with tree building--to get a correct tree.

> <sub>**side note** - and a handy utility method?</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Here's the compiled IL code generated for the method invoked by the `func` delegate just shown.
>
> ```
> IL_0000: ldc.i4.s   48
> IL_0002: ldc.i4.1   
> IL_0003: sub        
> IL_0004: ldc.i4.2   
> IL_0005: sub        
> IL_0006: ldc.i4.3   
> IL_0007: sub        
> IL_0008: ret
> ```
>
> Notice that, although our tree only contains `ConstantExpression` values which are integer constants, `Expression.Subtract` and most (if not all) of the other `BinaryExpression` types do not recognize the case where the `Left` and `Right` sides are both numerical constants as a reducible case.
>
> This can be remedied with an extension method utility that performs this reduction where possible:
>
> ```
> public static Expression ReduceConstants(this Expression expr)
> {
>     if (expr is ConstantExpression)
>         return expr;
>
>     if ((expr = expr.Reduce()) is BinaryExpression be &&
>         (be.Left.ReduceConstants()) is ConstantExpression &&
>         (be.Right.ReduceConstants()) is ConstantExpression)
>     {
>         var Tdel = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(expr.Type);
>         var del = Expression.Lambda(Tdel, be).Compile();
>         return Expression.Constant(del.DynamicInvoke(), expr.Type);
>     }
>     return expr;
> }
> ```
>
> Calling this extension method just once in the in the original example, prior to extracting the lambda, further reduces the expression so that it now gives considerably reduced code that is functionally equivalent.
>
> ```
> var seq = new[] { 48, 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => Expression.Constant(i));
> var root = L_to_R_Forward(seq);  // '((48 - 1) - 2) - 3' 
> root = root.ReduceConstants();   // '(42)'               <--- added step
> var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(root).Compile();
> int result = func();             // result <-- 42 (ok!)
> ```
>
> Here's that IL:
>
> ```
> IL_0000: ldc.i4.s   42
> IL_0002: ret
> ```

Now let's consider the situation where you of course still require the correct behavior of the **left-branching** expression tree, but it so happens that the sequence of linear operations is ***presented to you in reverse*** of its *intended* order, meaning it is still subject to left-to-right operator precedence. In this case, the procedure just described will not work and you need to adjust accordingly somehow. Returning to the example, if we reverse the original sequence, but still want the tree from its original order, we get an error:

```
seq = seq.Reverse();  // now: { 3, 2, 1, 48 }

root = L_to_R_Forward(seq);       // '(((3 - 2) - 1) - 48)'

func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(root).Compile();

result = func(); // result <-- -48 (ERROR)
```

Students in a typical introductory Computer Science course know that one way to fix this situation and get the correct tree from a reversed sequence is via **recursion**, whereby you write a function that always assumes it's building the root node. If such a function discovers that it can't complete because some of its children are missing it simply calls itself to get them.

For the current example, a recursive solution would temporarily hold the `Expression` for `3`  in a **recursive stack frame**, delaying its use until after its leftwards sibling `Expression` `((48 - 1) - 2)` becomes available. In recursive tree-building, constructing a parent node is deferred until all of its children are definitively known and final. In a certain sense then, building the root node is the first, last, and only step.

Although the recursive solution to reverse-tree building is simple and, in fact, ***canonically elegant***, it would also possible to get the correct result using a simple loop by mutating the tree as you proceed along in reverse.

Unfortunately, the `Left` and `Right` properties of a `BinaryExpression` are read-only, so normally you cannot mutate expression trees. Immutability would perhaps be expected for a finalized or compiled tree, but in this case you also aren't allowed to mutate a tree during the process of building it. Expressions do, however, support a concept of "reduction," which allows a way to rewrite them.

The following simple class is an "extension expression" which implements a simple mutable node of an `Expression` tree. You can set an instance of this custom `Expression` into any expression tree, and then the set its `Node` property to the actual desired expression. It acts as a ***proxy*** for the true, desired node. Unlike `ConstantExpression` or `BinaryExpression`, however, its `Node` property is read/write, so you can change the value of the proxied expression at any time prior to when `Reduce` is called during actual evaluation.

```
public class ExpressionRef : Expression
{
    public override ExpressionType NodeType => ExpressionType.Extension;
    public override Type Type => Node.Type;
    public override bool CanReduce => true;

    public Expression Node;
    public override Expression Reduce() => Node;

    public override String ToString() => "&" + Node;
};
```

I put the `'&'` symbol on the printout for the proxied nodes so you can see where they get embdeed in the expression tree printouts. The above class works perfectly for these demo purposes, but is therefore considerably simplified as well. You can imagine a lot of improvements that aren't shown here.

Using this we now have the ability to directly mutate an expression tree by explicitly rearranging its nodes using straightforward imperative code (as opposed to via rewriter classes or the use of more general-purpose `ParameterExpression` instances). This allows us to now write a correct non-recursive version of the tree builder example.

<sub>(Note that **C# 7** is assumed throughout; this next function in particular is much simplified by using 'ref locals'.)</sub>

```
public static Expression L_to_R_Reverse(IEnumerable<Expression> seq)
{
    Expression root = null;
    ExpressionRef prv = null;

    foreach (var cur in seq)
        if (root != null)
        {
            ref Expression pn_prv = ref (prv == null ? ref root : ref prv.Node);
            pn_prv = Expression.Subtract(prv = new ExpressionRef { Node = cur }, pn_prv);
        }
        else
            root = cur;

    return root;
}
```

And finally, the code to show that this function, while reading the nodes in reversed order, gives us the correct tree.

```
// 'seq' still reversed from earlier:  { 3, 2, 1, 48 }

var root_rev = L_to_R_Reverse(seq);    // '(&(&(&48 - 1) - 2) - 3)'

func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(root_rev).Compile();

result = func(); // result <-- 42 (ok!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression model just like you create an expression in any language. Of course you can use temp variables, if the expression goes too complicated:

```
 Expression result = Expression.Or(a, Expression.And(b, c));
```

In term of mathematics this is practically the Polish notation, where the form of the operation (for binary operators) is `<operator> <operand1> <operand2>`, like `+ 3 4` or `OR a b`. or `OR a AND b c`. About Polish notation please start read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

Comment: This is what I am already doing. So I first create a then create be and append to a and then create c and append to whatever the result of a and b was ... and so on. My issue is that the first expression becomes one whole expression instead of individual atomic expressions.

Comment: No, you are doing: Expression result = Expression.AND(c, Expression.OR(a, b)); (which is btw satisfies your _changed_ question's expectation)

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are always evaluated by their the [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx). Identical operators are often associative and evaluated from left to right.

So for your example of `a || b && c`, since the conditional And has a higher precedence than the conditional Or, the expression is equivalent to `a || (b && c)`. This is guaranteed by the grammar of the C# grammar. So the proper expression for this is `Expression.Or(a, Expression.And(b, c))`.

Similarly, all these expressions can be reduced to a sequence of 2-ary operations. Note that this can actually be a benefit because you can be as explicit as possible and you don’t need to remember the exact operator precedence for everything.

Comment: A bit of a background. I have an xml file based of which the user creates expressions. That expression list can have n number of expressions in there. with either an AND or an OR. I loop through each expression node and create an expression and combine it with the previous one. From what I understand of your answer, are you suggesting that I first combine all the ANDs and then the ORs?

Comment: I was just saying that `a || b && c` is equivalent to `a || (b && c)` because of operator precedence because ANDs are evaluated before ORs. If you are building your expressions from an XML, you might want to think about building a proper parser for it.